# Why is a line in this python function necessary? (memoized recursion)

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

I got the following code snippet from Peter Norvig's website; it's a decorator to enable memoization on function calls (caching prior calls to the function to change an exponential recursion into a simple dynamic program).

```
def memo(f):
    table = {}
    def fmemo(*args):
        if args not in table:
            table[args] = f(*args)
        return table[args]
    fmemo.memo = table
    return fmemo
```

The code works fine, but I'm wondering why the second to last line is necessary. This is clearly a gap in my knowledge of Python, but removing the line and running a simple fibonacci function, it still seems to work. Does this have to do with memoizing multiple functions simultaneously? Why would the member variable of fmemo be called memo (assuming it's not an awkward coincidence)?

Thanks!

Comment: Indentation of your code does not look right. Is that a nested function?

Comment: BTW this has been implement in Python 3.2 as [`functools.lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: @MAK: that is a nested function. This is the declaration for a decorator

Comment: @Bean: Indentation has been fixed after my comment. NVM.

Comment: My bad! Must have been a bad copy/paste.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since functions are objects just like anything else, you can set attributes on them. See:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
>>> foo.x = 1
>>> foo.x
1
```

The second-to-line sets the internal cache of values as an attribute on the function object, thus exposing it. This means that you can take a memoised function and fiddle with its cache as you will, without having to call it. This might be convenient.

---

Example:

```
>>> @memo
... def id(x): return x
>>> id(1)
1
>>> id(2)
2
>>> id.memo
{(2,): 2, (1,): 1}
```

Comment: I'd add to this that it's not *necessary*, due to the closure. As you say, the ability to meddle with it or access the values without needing to call it is going to be the important thing.

Comment: Indeed, the closed-over `table` variable also names the cache (which is actually problematic if `memo` is reassigned outside)... but +1.

Comment: Indeed, reassigning `memo` would be bad.

Comment: so I'm guessing there's no way to access closed over variables without pointing to them via attributes.

Comment: @Bean: corrent; in general, you can't look into someone else's scope. That's what scopes are for!

Comment: @Bean: you can look at a function's func_closure tuple.

Comment: What if the function `id()` had a member variable called memo?